# How to implement Mobile express checkout using php

Tags: php

I have created one php page and upon click of "Checkpres checkout" just redirecting into paypal sandbox url, however it's not working. We are using the php url in android webview to do payment everything. So i need your help to solve the problem. What are the information i need to POST to mobile paypal express checkout and with return, cancel url details?